# Calling a function to a button in javascript from a different javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I am trying to use a button to call and use a function from another javascript file if someone can help and shed some light on my problem thank you also the button is made in a javascript file as well. Here is the code of the button I've made using javascript

```
//Creating button
var button = document.createElement("button");
button.innerHTML = "English";

// 2. Append somewhere
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
body.appendChild(button);

// 3. Add event handler
button.addEventListener ("click", function() {
  alert("ENG");
});
```

Comment: What is the problem? The code looks fine

Comment: You can reference both scripts in the same HTML file. If you need a function from script 1, make sure script 1 is being called first.

Comment: Which code is in which file?  There are no functions being defined.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat thank you for replying, the problem is that the function was written in a different JavaScript file so I’m wondering how do I call it so it utilizes the function from the other file

Comment: @JosanIracheta thanks for replying, the problem is that the button is written in a JavaScript file not in a html file we’re you can import